# Get a child class when looping through its parent class java

Tags: java

I am looping through my Media arraylist ArrayList that has some child classes (Audio,Video,Picture)
And when I loop through my Media arraylist

```
public double getTotalVideoRunTime()
    {
        int total = 0;
        for(Media v : mList)
        {
            if(v.isVideo())
            {

            }
        }
        return total;
    }
```

I'm not sure how to get 'runtime' which is a variable from the video class, do I have to loop differently? I am not sure how I can get variables from child classes, I assume its possible(I hope!)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to call specific methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `instanceof` and cast it to the correct class.

e.g.

```
if(v instanceof Video){
Video a = (Video) v;
a.childMethodOfVideo();
}

if(v instanceof Audio){
Audio a = (Audio) v;
a.childMethodOfAudio();
}
```

Comment: usage of `instanceof` in this context is a huge code smell.

Comment: @amit Why would that be?

Comment: @MuratK. It is like a "large" if/else block or like switch: if you forget to keep that up to date, then this code is broken. It would be much better to use polymorphism here.

Comment: @Tom How could one use polymorphism to completely avoid making extensive use of if/else and switch statements? Thanks.

Comment: @MuratK. The fact that you call `chileMethodOfVideo()` and `childMethodOfAudio()`, instead of a concrete implementation of `childMethod()`, that is declared by `Media` and overriden by `Video` and `Audio`, is a code smell. It is handled MUCH more elegantly, efficiently, and easier to maintain with the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and polymorphism

Comment: @Unheilig Since I haven't wrote, that polymorphism can avoid _all_ of them, I can't answer that. The refactoring depends on the purpose of these blocks. You can avoid them with polymorphism, or with maps (e.g. `if (x.equals("..") { return "..."; } else if (x.equals("...") {return "...."; } ...` or with a other ways. There is no general way to do that.

Comment: @amit So as a example `Video` could have the method `play()` and `Image` could have `print()` _(He wrote it in the opening post that this class exist)._ How can you possibly use Polymorphism here and not instanceof?

Comment: @MuratK. I cannot think of a simple production code that uses `instanceof` that cannot be achieved with a better design and usage of polymorphism, with the exception of `equals()` implementation. If you are insisting on using it, be by guest - you are not my employee, but it is considered by most experts as a sign for bad design. [source1](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31), [source2](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnjava/comments/2j2n4o/why_is_instanceofcasting_considered_bad/), and I suggest open your mind and look for alternatives, that are always out there.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you want the *variables* a certain class has, you can use [reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) for it:

```
Field[] fields = v.getClass().getFields();
for (Field f : fields) System.out.println(f.getName());
```

Similarly if you want the methods:

```
Method[] methods = v.getClass().getMethods()();
for (Method m : methods) m.invoke(arguments...);
```

I must warn you that using reflection has a lot of cons (performance, safety) - and many times if you need to use it, it indicates a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

---

If you are trying to do some specific behavior for a certain class, the correct way to do it is implement it as abstract method, and call it - the dynamic type will be chosen, and the desired method will be called:

```
public abstract static class Media { 
    abstract public void foo();
}
public static class Video extends Media{
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("video");

    }
}
public static class Image extends Media{
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("image");

    }
}

public static void main(String ar[]) {
    Media m = new Video();
    m.foo();
}
```

Comment: I think he simply wants to access the child methods.

Comment: How does a abstract class solve this situation at all? He has a List containing child classes with possibly child specific methods.

Comment: @MuratK. you catch the common behavior in an interface / abstract class and make the concrete implementations take care of the differences. This is EXACTLY the role of abstract methods.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But in this case he has every object in a ArrayList where you have no idea if _object_ has the _concrete_ method.

Comment: @MuratK. By declaribg an abstract method of Media you force every implementing class to implement that method. That's thr point of it. Declaring the list as List<Media> ensures every object has implementation of it

Comment: @MuratK. If his current structure makes it hard for him to implement the suggested feature, then he should update his question, so we can help him there.

Comment: @MuratK. Let's give him some time :). Maybe he wil come back to answer our questions.